# Output the sd in a single cell in the data.frame

Tags: r

I'd like to calculate the sd of the 4-5 values in the data. That's my data:

```
> dput(head(tbl_mut1[,-1]))
structure(list(timetE1_1rerun = c(6692.50136510743, 41682.9111356503, 
405946.374877924, 4640.34876265179, 240390.441186252, 703123.176341707
), timetE2_1 = c(14404.8414547167, 40466.9047986558, 638019.540242027, 
2397.71968447607, 393232.499257675, 1197307.39205423), timetE2_1rerun = c(10146.3608040476, 
34148.4389867747, 459639.431186888, 10490.8359468475, 288806.94715668, 
975519.82880571), timetE3_1 = c(5951.82142983062, 45616.664822506, 
658598.827475944, 3961.96726959746, 343020.546938455, 909826.309486319
), timetE4_1 = c(4048.60493244488, 45729.9856907985, 639686.154465906, 
4466.15324797652, 304709.302766716, 863215.201742023), timetE1_2 = c(59094.47562632, 
139889.207295753, 1764684.16499658, 26250.3247678529, 229006.578252829, 
607148.289529371), timetE2_2 = c(27675.589438082, 111309.636536099, 
1117027.2897719, 20320.0802981216, 210671.007373094, 634380.157923317
), timetE3_2 = c(26374.057451648, 129781.168773572, 1147967.44539752, 
18413.5391459416, 215091.483121199, 558724.345729093), timetE4_2 = c(43310.0075838041, 
96924.6162599508, 1156442.475223, 29061.2479135303, 181601.087180429, 
509169.534226553), eve_mean = c(7774.44229552491, 43374.1166119026, 
585562.72426545, 3866.54724117546, 320338.197537275, 918368.01990607
), mor_mean = c(39113.5325249635, 119476.157216344, 1296530.34384725, 
23511.2980313616, 209092.538981888, 577355.581852083), tot_mean = c(23443.9874102442, 
81425.1369141232, 941046.53405635, 13688.9226362685, 264715.368259581, 
747861.800879077), tot_meanwte = c(258492586.999527, 258492586.999527, 
258492586.999527, 258492586.999527, 258492586.999527, 258492586.999527
), tot_meanwtm = c(246665241.110832, 246665241.110832, 246665241.110832, 
246665241.110832, 246665241.110832, 246665241.110832), tot_sdwte = c(16743477.4011497, 
16743477.4011497, 16743477.4011497, 16743477.4011497, 16743477.4011497, 
16743477.4011497), tot_sdwtm = c(3922418.43271348, 3922418.43271348, 
3922418.43271348, 3922418.43271348, 3922418.43271348, 3922418.43271348
)), .Names = c("timetE1_1rerun", "timetE2_1", "timetE2_1rerun", 
"timetE3_1", "timetE4_1", "timetE1_2", "timetE2_2", "timetE3_2", 
"timetE4_2", "eve_mean", "mor_mean", "tot_mean", "tot_meanwte", 
"tot_meanwtm", "tot_sdwte", "tot_sdwtm"), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I skept the first column because there are a lot of names which will bring a tons of code. 
I used this code to calculate the sd and output in the next column:

```
tbl3 <- sd(c(tbl_mut1[445,2],tbl_mut1[445,3],tbl_mut1[445,4],tbl_mut1[445,5],tbl_mut1[445,6]))

tbl_mut1["tot_sdwte"] <- NA
tbl_mut1$tot_sdwte <- tbl3
```

The problem is that I have the result in whole column and I just want to have it in a single "cell" of the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data frames are lists made up of vectors of the same length.  These vectors are the columns.  That is why when you add a single value to a data frame, it appears as the whole column.

To get around this, you can do something like this:

```
tbl_mut1$tot_sdwte <- c(tbl3, rep(NA, dim(tbl_mut1)[1] - 1))
```

This adds a vector with the first value as the standard deviation and the rest of the values are missing.

Comment: Somehow it solves my problem anyway would be better to just leave the "cell" empty instead of putting NA in whole column. I believe it's not possbile so thx for that solution.

Comment: @Rechlay you should try not to think of data elements as "cells."  That's an Excel hangover :-) .  Data reside in *locations* in a vector or dataframe or list object.

Comment: I used Excell for a long time. There are much more data to analyse that's why I am trying to learn how R works. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: `NA` is R's version of an 'empty' cell.  Still, it is important to think of things as @CarlWitthoft indicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append an informative bit of summary to a data.frame there is the option of making an "attribute":

```
attr(tbl_mut1, "tot_sdwte") <- tbl3
?attr
```

That attribute could be anything. (I am wondering about the code you used for tbl3's construction however. It appears you would only have gotten the `sd` of row 445 for columns 2-6 (six values) and if that was what you wanted, then just use: `sd(tbl_mut1[445,2:6])`